# How to add values to an object with properties as arrays?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In the SSRS 2010 service there is this class:

```
Partial Public Class [Property]
    Private nameField As String
    Private valueField As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.nameField = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And I'm having a devil of a time trying to figure out how to add this name\value pair:

Name = "MimeType"
Value = "image/jpeg"

Should be easy, right?  Here's what I've tried:

```
    Dim Prop As New ReportingServices2010WebSvc.Property
    Prop.Name = "MimeType"
    Prop.Value = "image/jpeg"
```

This gets me:

```
 Value of type 'ReportingServices2010WebSvc.Property' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of ReportingServices2010WebSvc.Property'
```

Or this:

```
    Dim Prop() As ReportingServices2010WebSvc.Property ' <- Won't let me use New
    Prop(0).Name = "MimeType"
    Prop(0).Value = "image/jpeg"
```

But this tells me:

```
 Variable 'Prop' is sued before it has been assigned a value.  Null exception could result at runtime
```

Anyway, I keep trying different combos, and it either won't compile, or complies but then throws an error at runtime.

Help?!!?  This SHOULD be easy.

**EDIT AFTER -- Answer:**

As I suspected, I was making this harder than it needed to be.

```
    Dim Prop As New ReportingServices2010WebSvc.Property
    Prop.Name = "MimeType"
    Prop.Value = "image/jpeg"
```

Then, we passing Prop into a method that wants it as an array, I just put {} around it:

```
 CreateCatalogItem("thing1, "thing2", {Prop}, Nothing)
```

Comment: Ok, I figured this out.  The problem was not in creating the instance of the class.  It was in passing that instance into a method that wanted it as an array.  I'll edit the question so the answer will be formatted.